# Can a numerical method's order of convergence be higher than theoretical for a "lucky" function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have an ODE $du/dx=\psi'+p(u-\psi (x))^4, u(0)=0$, $x$ goes from 0 to 1, which i solve using Runge-Kutta method:
\begin{align}
k_1&=hf(x_i,u_i),
\\
k_2&=hf(x_i+h/2,u_i+k_1/2),
\\
k_3&=hf(x_i+h,u_i-k_1+2k_2),
\\
u_{i+1}&=u_i+(k_1+4k_2+k_3)/6
\end{align}

Its theoretical rate of convergence should be $3$, but calculating numerically for a given function $\psi$, i get that its rate of convergence is $4$, which would mean that in Taylor's series expansion, the method matches the infinite series up to $O(h^5)$'s term inclusive, for every iteration step (they are the same for the terms up to $O(h^4)$ because it is theoretically so). I can't check it manually, on paper, because it is too much work and calculations are huge to calculate all the partial derivatives up to 4th order. There is 18 terms in the expression for $f'''(x,u)$ already!

So my question is, is it a given that i have a mistake somewhere in my code, or can it be that for my function, the order is one level higher, because $(h^4/4!)f''''$ minus $O(h^4)$-th part of $u_{i+1}=u_i+(k_1+4k_2+k_3)/6$ equals zero on the whole interval from $0$ to $1$? Or is that nonsense?

When i use another 3-rd order Runge-Kutta method, with different coefficients, i get the "correct" 3-th order of convergence for my solution which suggests that my code is right. Any thoughts?

My functions are $\psi (x)=\sin(\pi x)$ and $\psi (x)=\ln(1+x)$, if that helps.

Comment: Can you give more details on how you got the order? Where did you measure the error, only at $x=1$ or at more points in the interval?

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann added my $\psi$ in the edit. I calculated $u$ for amount of steps n=5,n=10,n=20, and etc. and calculated the difference between $u$ and the solution as the maximum of absolute value of the difference for $xi$, i goes from 0 to n. And the result was that when i double n, the error decreases 16 times, which gives me the 4th order of convergence. While it should be 3.

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconvergence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible for this special case of a test equation. As long as $u$ is close to the exact solution $\phi$, you have $u(t)-\phi(t)=O(h^3)$ by the method itself, so that the term $p(u(t)-\phi(t))^4$ is of size $O(h^{12})$. Removing this term from the equation gives thus a contribution to the global error of size $O(h^{11})$, and thus this small perturbation will not influence the order.

What remains is the integration of $u'(t)=\phi'(t)$, and the RK3 method reduces to the Simpson quadrature method, which is a fourth order method. This is the order you observe. Other 3rd order RK methods will mostly reduce to quadrature methods of order 3.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was of great help!